# google maps v3 with geometry and places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I want to use google maps v3 in my phonegap jquery mobile page and I need the geometry AND the places library.

If I include this code in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

I get this error and the geometry function doesn't work too:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

---

If I delete `&libraries=geometry`, the autocomplete works, but not the geometry functions
If I delete `&libraries=places`, the geometry function works, but not the autocomplete

How can I use both libraries?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```